# document.body is null or not an object

Tags: javascript

I am getting Java script error while loading page:
document.body is null or not an object.
URL:
https://admit-uat.belgacom.be/WCE/ESW/selectBundle/productId/bun_nettv_go

Can you please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code?

Comment: The link you posted doesn't work for me. I get a time out

Comment: you should [read the Stackoverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and learn how people communicate on this site. Elaborating on your questions should not be done by adding "answers" that aren't answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // wait for the DOCUMENT to become ready.
        window.onload=function(){
          walkmydog()
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Here's a detailed explanation for overcoming this sort of problem: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml

Comment: 'code'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.sourceforge.net/" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<div>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Belgacom</title>
        <!--ls:begin[stylesheet]-->
        <style type="text/css">
            body {'

Answer (score 1):

May be late but helpful...

You have to make sure you are calling the document.body after the `<body>` tag is loaded not before it.

**This WILL NOT work:**

```
<html>
     <head>
         <script>
              document.body.onload = function(){
                  alert('document Loaded');
               }
</script>

      </head>

      <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

**This WILL work**

```
<head>    

    </head>

    <body >        

<script>
    document.body.onload = function(){
    alert('document Loaded');
    }
    </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

**This also WILL work**

```
</head>

<body onload = "function foo(){
alert('document Loaded');

   } foo();">


</body>

</html>
```

However, if you insist of having the `Javascript` before the `<body>` tag, You could go for `jQuery`'s

```
$(function(){

//.....Your code here.
})
```

This is also one way to guard against cross-browser issues.

Hop that helps!